# Html/php/mysql forms are not submitting and redirecting issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

i'm working on a dashboard for my users. I set it up by ranks and each rank can do there own thing. Now, I have three problems. One and two are about forms and another is about a redirection problem. These forms are not submitting into the database and I don't know why. The two forms are below. The third problem is redirecting. Since the system is setup by ranks I don't want ranks accessing other ranks dashboards. Its not redirecting the other ranks away from there dashboard as its all one login and when those ranks login it redirects them to there correct dashboard, but if say a partner goes to the admin dashboard, it lets them in which I don't want. Also I forgot to mention that when the user is logged in, it lets them back to the login page if they go to the login url which I don't want, I want it to redirect them to there dashboard. The forms are below.

First Form:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id = '.$id.'");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $username1 = $_POST['username'];
  $email1 = $_POST['email'];
  $password1 = $_POST['password'];
  $f_name = $_POST['f_name'];
  $l_name = $_POST['l_name'];
  $rank1 = $_POST['rank'];
  $skype1 = $_POST['skype'];

  $db->query("UPDATE users SET (Email, Username, FName, LName, Rank, SkypeID) VALUES(''.$email1.'', ''.$username1.'', ''.$f_name.'', ''.$l_name.'', ''.$rank1.'', ''.$skype1.'') WHERE Id = ".$id."");
}

?>

<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
  $username = $row['Username'];
  $email = $row['Email'];
  $fname = $row['FName'];
  $lname = $row['LName'];
  $rank = $row['Rank'];
  $skype = $row['SkypeID'];
}
?>
<form method="POST">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo ($username); ?>"><br>
  Email: <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo ($email);?>"><br>
  Passowrd: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
  First Name: <input type="text" name="f_name" value="<?php echo ($fname);?>"><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="l_name" value="<?php echo($lname); ?>"><br>
  Rank: <input type="text" name="rank" value="<?php echo ($rank); ?>"><br>
  Skype: <input type="text" name="rank" value="<?php echo ($skype); ?>">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Update User</button>
</form>
```

Second Form:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
  $v_link = $_POST['v_link'];
  $v_title = $_POST['v_title'];
  $v_desc = $_POST['v_desc'];
  $v_tags = $_POST['v_tags'];
  $m_sources = $_POST['m_sources'];
  $s_requests = $_POST['s_requests'];

  if(empty($c_name) or empty($v_link) or empty($v_title) or empty($v_title) or empty($v_desc) or empty($v_tags))
  {
    echo 'You must fill in the first 5 fields.';
  }
  else
  {
    $getRank = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ".$_SESSION['username']."");
    while ($row = $getRank->fetch_assoc($getRank))
    {
      $usename = $row['username'];
      $rank = $row['rank'];
    }
    $db->query("INSERT INTO submitted_forms (username, rank, channel_username, video_link, video_title, video_description, video_tags, music_sources, special_requests) VALUES (''.$username.'', ''.$rank.'', ''.$c_name.'', ''.$v_link.'', ''.$v_title.'', ''.$v_desc.'', ''.$v_tags.'', ''.$m_sources.'', ''.$s_requests.'')");
    echo 'Form submitted successfully.';
    }
  }
?>

<form method="POST">
  Channel name: <input type="text" name="c_name" required>*<br>
  Video Link: <input type="text" name="v_link" required>*<br>
  Video Title: <input type="text" name="v_title" required>*<br>
  Video Description: <input type="text" name="v_desc" required>*<br>
  Video Tags: <input type="text" name="v_tags" required>*<br>
  Music Sources: <input type="text" name="m_sources"><br>
  Special Requests: <input type="text" name="s_requests"><br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button><br>
</form>
```

Now, heres the code I use to redirect a user away from the dashboards if its not there dashboard. It redirects not logged in users, but not like other users. Its supposed to only allow admins in.

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['admin']))
{
$_SESSION['username'];

} else {
  header("location: ../index.php");
} ?>
```

Now, heres the login script. I want it to redirect the ranks to there dashboard if they're logged in, I don't know how to implant this.

```
<?php
require 'core/config.php';


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $username = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
  $password = md5($_POST['password']);

  if(empty($username) or empty($password))
  {
    echo 'You must fill in both boxes!';
  } else {
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
    {
      $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
    }

    if($password !== $dbpassword)
    {
      echo 'Password was incorrect.';
    } else {
      $query1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");
      while($rows = $query1->fetch_assoc())
      {
        $rank = $rows['Rank'];
      }

      if($rank === 'admin')
      {
        $_SESSION['admin'] = '1';
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        echo '<script>window.location="management/index.php";</script>';
      }
      elseif ($rank === 'partner')
      {
        $_SESSION['partner'] = '1';
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

       echo '<script>window.location="partner/index.php";</script>';
      }
      elseif ($rank === 'trainee')
      {
         $_SESSION['trainee'] = '1';
         $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        echo '<script>window.location="trainee/index.php";</script>';
      }
      else 
      {
        echo 'Account not found.';
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Put <?php session_start(); ?> In your Login Page Please.

Comment: Wait, its in there. Its at the very top. I just copied the whole php part

Comment: It was in there from before and thats not the problem. The login works fine

Comment: _“These forms are not submitting into the database and I don't know why”_ – forms don’t communicate with a database, your script does. And you have not given a sh*t about what might be wrong with your database queries – so go read up on how to do some proper error handling when it comes to database queries, and then implement it.

Comment: No need to be an ass about it. I'm still learning. I know that the script does, thats what I meant.

Comment: solve first the redirecting of pages, before going down with the saving in your database. it's like from general to specific problem

Answer (score 0):

try this in your login script:

```
<?php
require 'core/config.php';

//assuming that you have already start your session at the very top

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$username = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

if(empty($username) or empty($password))
{
echo 'You must fill in both boxes!';
} else {
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
  $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
}

if($password !== $dbpassword)
{
  echo 'Password was incorrect.';
} else {
  $query1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");
  while($rows = $query1->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $rank = $rows['Rank'];
  }

  if($rank === 'admin')
  {
    $_SESSION['rank'] = $rank;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    echo '<script>window.location="management/index.php";</script>';
  }
  else if ($rank === 'partner')
  {
    $_SESSION['rank'] = $rank;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

   echo '<script>window.location="partner/index.php";</script>';
  }
  else if ($rank === 'trainee')
  {
     $_SESSION['rank'] = $rank;
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    echo '<script>window.location="trainee/index.php";</script>';
  }
  else 
  {
    echo 'Account not found.';
  }
 }
}
}
?>
```

in your management/index.php or in the page where supposed to only allow admins in.

```
 <?php session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['rank']) and $_SESSION['rank'] == "admin")
  {
  $_SESSION['username'];

  } else {
  header("location: ../index.php");
  } ?>
```

and with you saving, you just maybe forget the right quotations:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
 $v_link = $_POST['v_link'];
 $v_title = $_POST['v_title'];
 $v_desc = $_POST['v_desc'];
 $v_tags = $_POST['v_tags'];
 $m_sources = $_POST['m_sources'];
 $s_requests = $_POST['s_requests'];

 if(empty($c_name) or empty($v_link) or empty($v_title) or empty($v_title) or empty($v_desc) or empty($v_tags))
 {
   echo 'You must fill in the first 5 fields.';
 }
 else
 {
  $getRank = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'");
while ($row = $getRank->fetch_assoc($getRank))
 {
   $usename = $row['username'];
   $rank = $row['rank'];
 }
 $db->query("INSERT INTO submitted_forms (username, rank, channel_username, video_link, video_title, video_description, video_tags, music_sources, special_requests) VALUES ('$username', '$rank', '$c_name', '$v_link', '$v_title', '$v_desc', '$v_tags', '$m_sources', '$s_requests')");
echo 'Form submitted successfully.';
 }
 }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this and now i'm getting a bunch of 'Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /:1) in /index.php on line 1'

Comment: For the form that you gave me, i'm getting this error, also on the original one ´Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in  on line 37´

Comment: Mind later about the insertion of data in the database, but first focus on the redirecting of the page, "Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /:1) in /index.php on line 1" = this means that the you already started a session, does your index.php has an include("somePHPpageHEre.php")?

Comment: I don't have a include file on the page. I did it on multiple pages and both don't have one. The session start is all the way at the top so it can't be white spaces. I have no idea what it is. I'm going to try the edited version of the form now. Now, can you see about the other form I posted as well?

Comment: Didn't updated your first form yet, let's just make it step by step. We must try the redirecting first if it's okay with you.

Comment: Alright yeah thats fine and I just tried the new form and it didn't work, got the same error. For the redirection I have an includes file, but it doesn't start a session in that file. I tried it on another page and it worked just fine so I have no idea what the problem is

Comment: If it's okay with you, can you send me or post here the whole codes of your index.php

Comment: Heres <?php session_start(); ?>
  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['rank']) and $_SESSION['rank'] == "partner")
  {
  $_SESSION['username'];

  } else {
  echo '<script>window.location="../index.php";</script>';
  }
        include "header.php"; 
        include "menu.php"; ?>

Comment: Why does this code is included in login.php? <?php if(isset($_SESSION['rank']) and $_SESSION['rank'] == "partner") { $_SESSION['username']; }else { echo '<script>window.location="../index.php";</script>'; }, this is just suppose to check if the user is a partner or admin right? So why having this code here? Also check your header.php and menu.php if they have session_start.

Comment: This isn't in the login. I also did check the header and menu files and both don't have session start.